# How to set "pageSize" with the java client of the Google Photos API

Tags: java, android, google-photos-api

We are using the Google Photos API java client on Android to retrieve some of the user's photo with this code:

```java
try(PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient = PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)) {
    InternalPhotosLibraryClient.SearchMediaItemsPagedResponse libraryResponse = photosLibraryClient.searchMediaItems(filters);
    Iterable<InternalPhotosLibraryClient.SearchMediaItemsPage> listMediaItemsPage = libraryResponse.iteratePages();

    for (InternalPhotosLibraryClient.SearchMediaItemsPage mediaItemsPage : listMediaItemsPage) {
    /* ... */
    }
}
```

Our problem is that the `mediaItemsPage` only retrieve up to 25 `mediaItem` by default. According to [the Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list#pagination) it's possible to move that number up to 100 by setting the "pageSize" parameter. However when using the Java client we cannot find how to correctly set this parameter.

There is a `libraryResponse.iterateFixedSizeCollections(collectionSize);` but looking at the method's doc it says:

> it is an error to call this method if the optional parameter 'page_size' has not been
>      * set in the original API call. It is also an error if the collectionSize parameter is less than
>      * the page_size.

What is the "original API call"? What are the steps required in order to set `pageSize` correctly?

Comment: Hey @Gauthier I'm facing error in Google photos api, can you please provide us code?